# Period of $f(x) = \cos^2 ax - \cos^4 ax$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ what is $a$?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I can not access the solutions I just know the correct answer which is $2$.
I tried to solve the problem and I got $4$ instead here is my solution:
$\cos^2 ax(1 - \cos^2 ax) = \cos^2 ax \sin^2 ax = 1/4 \sin^2 (2ax)$
and then to get the period
$2\pi/|2a| = \pi/4$
which result that $a$ is $+4$ or $-4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint: $a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b)$. If you see squared terms its **generally** better to assign them with a variable. Like, let $k = \cos(ax)$. Then you get, $k^2(1 - k^2)$. See how its more cleaner, and you can generally think of more ways of solving it in this format.

**Edit**: My bad for not understanding the question clearly.

To the find the period, you can try condensing the your multi-trigonometric function in to a linear form, and your already halfway there. The identities:

$$\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$$
$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$$

If you substitute these into your answer, you get:
$$\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$$
$$\frac{1}{4}(1-\cos^2(2x))$$
$$\frac{1}{4}(\sin^2(2x))$$

Another identity is:

$$\sin(x)\sin(y)= \frac{1}{2}(\cos(x - y) - \cos(x + y))$$

$\frac{1}{4}(\sin^2(2x))$ can be split into $\frac{1}{4}(\sin(2x)\sin(2x))$, where your $y$ would just be $x$. So it would become:

$$\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{2}(\cos(0)-\cos(4x))) = \frac{1-\cos(4x)}{8}$$

Hence, your period is $\frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Your solution is affected by the period. As the functions are periodic, so will your solutions be periodic. They will repeat every period. (there is a solution for $x = 0$, and there will another solution for every $\pm \frac{\pi}{2})$. (i.e. there will be a solution at $-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$ and so on...). Therefore, solutions from $0$ are every +$\frac{\pi n}{2}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Should I expand $sin^2 (ax)$ ? if so, how?

Comment: @Erfan No, I meant, do you need to go through the effort to to obtain $\sin$ when your function consists of only $\cos$, I will rephrase my answer for clarity

Comment: I got what you mean so how can I get the period of two cos subtracted?

Comment: Oh, so you are looking for the period as well as the roots?

Comment: No roots just the period. By the way I don't know if roots are related to finding the period.

Comment: Yes, they are, I will edit my answer...

Comment: so I should convert to linear trig functions not exponential to know about the period?

Comment: What if I get to linear functions subtracted can I use the LCM of their periods?

Comment: @Erfan Even with subtraction it is mostly possible to reduce it to a singular form, so you do not really need to worry. Yes it is better to convert exponential forms of periodic functions, like sin, cos and tan to their linear forms. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometric-identities.html - have a look here for more.